# Join of 2 Set Exec Strings in TSQL

Tags: t-sql

I have 2 select statements inside of strings setup like this:

```
set @sql = 'Select.......' -- (Returns col1, col2, col3)
exec (@sql)

set @sql = 'Select.......' -- (Returns col4, col5, col6)
exec (@sql)
```

I want to Join these 2 exec statements so that the columns will appear like this as a result:

```
col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 | col6
```

Any tips? Thanks.

Comment: That's a join, not a union.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why don't you simply write a proper join? Why use `EXEC` at all?

Comment: Not sure. Our DBA wrote this Stored Procedure 3 years ago and I am cutting it down to my needs so that I can use it as the back end to a program that I am writing. Basically all of these EXEC have filters in them that are set options in other tables that gain values from our programs.

Comment: How does col1,col2, col3 relate to col4, col5, col6? without that I don't see how you could join these into one record. without mis-matched results.

Comment: The data is going into multiple Excel worksheets, so the mismatch is ok. Basically the user will find what they are looking for on Sheet1 and then if they need to reference it, they go to Sheet2 where the extra data is. I solved this with an Inner Join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn on DATA ACCESS on your local server:

```
exec sp_serveroption @server = 'YourServerName' 
   ,@optname = 'DATA ACCESS' 
   ,@optvalue = 'TRUE'
```

And use OPENQUERY:

```
select 
    * 
from ( 
        select * from openquery(YourServerName,  'select 1 as a') 
        ) t1
    full join (
        select * from openquery(YourServerName,  'select 3 as b') 
) t2 
    on t1.a = t2.b
```

Comment: I keep returning an error stating that my t1 statement is too long. (Over 8000 characters, which is true)

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @SQL1  VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @SQL2 VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @SQL1='SELECT COL1,COL2,NULL AS COL3,NULL AS COL4 FROM #TEST1'
SET @SQL2='SELECT NULL,NULL, COL3, COL4 FROM #TEST2'

EXEC (@SQL1 +' UNION ALL '+ @SQL2)
```

Comment: Never mind that string concatenation is a very bad idea, the OP is actually asking about a JOIN, not a UNION.

Answer (score 0):

I got the result that I wanted by removing the EXEC and keeping them as plain Select statements. Then I performed an Inner Join to avoid NULLS. Thanks all for the help.